# Which first order logic logic equivalences are not valid in intuitionistic logic?

Tags: first-order-logic

I know that --A == A and -(A /\ B) == -A or -B don't hold in intuitionistic logic. Which are the relatives first order logic equivalence that don't hold in intuitionistic logic?

Comment: See [Intuitionistic logic](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-intuitionistic/#RejTerNonDat).

Comment: For example, it is not true that $\lnot \forall x \lnot Px$ is equivalent to $\exists x Px$.

Comment: There are lots of examples. For examples, some kind of de Morgan's law $\lnot (A\land B)\to \lnot A\lor \lnot B$ is not valid. $A\to B$ no longer implies $\lnot A\lor B$. You may find some examples by considering a statement under [BHK interpretation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brouwer%E2%80%93Heyting%E2%80%93Kolmogorov_interpretation).